# Proper way of storing ListView items' data - ResourceDictionary?

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, windows-10-universal, resourcedictionary

I am a complete beginner to C#, so forgive me if this question seems trivial.

I have a simple menu that is a ListView. Every item in the menu has text and image. Should these values be kept in a ResourceDictionary or should I create a list of these items somewhere in class and then bind them?

Comment: It depends on what this text represent. If it does not meant to be changing leave it there or move it to the resource file (such file should contain any text or that can change when user change the language). If it meant to be changing, you should bind text to view model. For now you can assume that the same apply to images.

Comment: I would use the ResourceDictionary. If you menu item says "Hello" and then you want to support another language, that is when it will pay off. Same for images. For example, logos differ based on language.

Answer (score 0):

If you never needed to reuse this piece of UI code, I would just put it inside page's resources; if it could be reused on another page, I would put it in a resource dictionary.

UI code belongs to XAML, it's much clearer to read this (and even view this in VS Designer)

```
<Button Content="Add" />
```

than

```
var button = new Button() { Content = "Add" };
this.myGrid.Children.Add(button);
```